# Change spacing of ordered list items using a div or span outside of the list itself without css for phpbb

Tags: html, html-lists

I wanted to add a `bbcode` for `phpbb` that allowed spacing between ordered list items without having to change configuration files which may be lost on updates.

I tried:

```
<div class="listspaced" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">{TEXT}</div>
```

but that doesn't work.  Is there a way to tell it to apply the margin to the `li` items inline?

The `{TEXT}` section is where the `<ol><li></li></ol>` items will be and the class is the name of the `bbcode` (that's how phpbb links the code to the html).

TIA!!